# Playing videostream on Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, google-cardboard

I try to play an incoming videostream on my Android App.
The stream is created by vlc on raspbian (RTSP and HTTP). I tryed to use the nativ android mediaplayer but it doesn't work.

The app should render the video side by side with the cardboard API. It works fine with a local file.

Do you have any ideas about alternatives for the mediaplayer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using ExoPlayer for this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html it will handle the streaming much better than mediaplayer